# Knockout.js click binding accessing model values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When alerting the property values inside the object I get a really weird alert message.

The alert call is located at where it saids ISSUE IS HERE *******.

The alert I am receiving is https://flic.kr/p/m1CYkD
`function c(){if0<arguments.length)returnc.equalityComparer&&c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0])} ......`

JS

```
$(function(){
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModelBooks());
});


function Book(title, checked_out_to, id)
{
  this.title = ko.observable(title);
  this.checked_out_to = ko.observable(checked_out_to);
  this.id = ko.observable(id);
}

function ViewModelBooks(){
  var self = this;
  self.library = ko.observableArray();

  self.checkOutBook = function(obj){
    alert(obj.title); <--- ISSUE IS HERE ********************
  };

  // Query all books
  var url = 'http://portal.internal.urs.org/tools_services/training_library/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Book?$expand=CheckedOutTo';
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
        var book = data.d.results[i];
        var checked_out_to = null;

        if (book.CheckedOutTo != null){
          checked_out_to = book.CheckedOutTo.Name;
        }
        self.library.push(new Book(book.Title, checked_out_to, book.Id));
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: library">
        <tr><td data-bind="text: title"></td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="ifnot: checked_out_to">
                    <button class="btn_checkout" type="button" 
                    data-bind="click: $parent.checkOutBook">Check Out</button>
                </span>
                <span data-bind="if: checked_out_to">
                    <span data-bind="text: checked_out_to"> </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `obj.title` is an `observable` (a function), you have to invoke it if you need its value.

Your code should be :

```
alert(obj.title()); // getter
obj.title('new value');  // setter
```

**[See doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables)**